# How translate s3 url to http in chrome automatically?

Tags: google-chrome, https, amazon-s3

Let say I have a link like that:

```
s3://mybucket/mybucket?prefix=myprefix/file.json
```

And I open it in chrome browser. I will get an error. Is it possible to automatically translate the s3 url from

```
s3://mybucket/mybucket?prefix=myprefix/file.json
```

to

```
https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/mybucket?prefix=myprefix/file.json
```

And got redirect/open aws s3 web consul?

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but it might solve your problem: have you seen [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fileon-s3-browser/dkckgdiclklkmiaimnpdlccihdkfbjdd?hl=en)?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bookmarklet to modify the links for you, but you'd have to run it every time you want to click a link.

eg:

```
javascript:(function(){document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach((l)=>{m=l.href.match(/^s3\:\/\/([^\/]+)\/([^$]+)$/);if(m){l.href=`https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/${m[2]}`}})})()
```

(haven't tested it, but should work?)